# Getting a Derieved class from the unique_ptr of abstract Base Type

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a case where I want to expose a clean API for spatial search structures.
Now I am conveniently represented the greater case in this toy example.
Here there are two abstract Base classes `ToySmall` and `ToyBig`, the instance of a derived type of `ToySmall` is created in the `returnSmall` method of an instance derived type of `ToyBig`.

Following are the contents of ToyInterface.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ToySmall
{
public:
   ToySmall() {}
   virtual void toyMethod() const = 0;
};

class ToyBig
{
public:
   ToyBig() {}
   virtual std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> returnSmall() = 0;
};
```

I have the return type of `returnSmall` as `std::unique_ptr<ToySmall>` in order to return co-variant type because each derived type of `ToyBig` returns a different derived type of `ToySmall`.

But while realizing these interfaces and using them as I intend to, I'm having issues getting the concrete instance of `ToySmallImpl` as I have in the file below. I have included the errors in the source below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ToyInterfaces.h"

class ToySmallImpl : public ToySmall
{
public:
  ToySmallImpl()
  : ToySmall()
  {}

  void toyMethod() const override
  {
    std::cout << "All Good!!" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ToyBigImpl : public ToyBig
{
public:
  ToyBigImpl()
  : ToyBig()
  {}

  std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> returnSmall() override
  {
    ToySmall* small;
    ToySmallImpl smallImpl;
    small = &smallImpl;
    return std::unique_ptr<ToySmall>(small);
  }
};

int main()
{
  ToyBigImpl bigImpl;
  std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> toySmall =  bigImpl.returnSmall();

  // ToySmallImpl toySmallImpl = *toySmall;
  // Error : error: conversion from ‘ToySmall’ to non-scalar type ‘ToySmallImpl’ requested

  ToySmallImpl toySmallImpl = static_cast<ToySmallImpl>(*toySmall);
  // Error : no matching function for call to ‘ToySmallImpl::ToySmallImpl(ToySmall&)’

  toySmallImpl.toyMethod();
}
```

Since the `Impl` classes are to be extended from the interfaces I have, and can be implemented by other developers too, I don't want to have a copy constructor or the `=` operator, as most other solutions point. If it were only for me, I'd have been more than happy getting this to work however I can. But, I want it to be clean so that I could present the solution as a guideline to other users of the API.

I am wondering if anyone else had a similar case and could point me to a possible solution where in `main` I'll be able to create an instance of `ToySmallImpl` and use it.

Comment: Your `returnSmall()` is returning the address of a local object, albeit wrapped in a `std::unique_ptr`.    That means the caller receives a pointer to an object that no longer exists - so any usage of the object by the caller gives undefined behaviour.    It also means undefined behaviour when the returned `unique_ptr` passes out of scope, since it attempts to release an object that not longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> returnSmall() override
{
    ToySmall* small;
    ToySmallImpl smallImpl;
    small = &smallImpl;
    return std::unique_ptr<ToySmall>(small); // Return dangling pointer
}
```

You return dangling pointer, you may simply do:

```
std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> returnSmall() override
{
    return std::make_unique<ToySmallImpl>();
}
```

Then, for polymorphic types, the "right" cast is `dynamis_cast`:

```
std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> toySmall =  bigImpl.returnSmall();

auto& toySmallImpl = dynamic_cast<ToySmallImpl&>(*toySmall);
toySmallImpl.toyMethod();
```

Comment: This works for the toy example, but I build the search structures using c++11, where make_unique is not available, do you have any advice of how that situation should be handled?

Comment: Implement `make_unique`: `template <typename T, typename ...Ts> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Ts&&...args) { return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code resembles more like a `Proxy Design Pattern.` Try this:

```
class ToyBigImpl : public ToyBig
{
public:
    ToyBigImpl()
        : ToyBig()
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> returnSmall() override
    {
        std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> small = std::make_unique<ToySmallImpl>();
        return std::move(small);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ToyBigImpl bigImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<ToySmall> toySmall = bigImpl.returnSmall();

    ToySmallImpl toySmallImpl = *(reinterpret_cast<ToySmallImpl*>(toySmall.get()));

    toySmallImpl.toyMethod();                                                                         
    return 0;
}
```